# Following all links recursively with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to crawl a website that is set out like a file directory. I'd like to follow all the links (unknown number of nested folders) until I get to the .xml and .pdf files, to then download.

Selenium seems like the best option because this sites requires a log in and also then sends a code to a phone app to log in. I've been able to log in using the web driver.

At the moment my code only navigates to the first 'end node' of the file tree. I'm not sure how to go back and go through all links. Any ideas? Here is my code so far...

```py
browser.get(start_url)
def crawler():
    links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//pre/a')
    for link in links:
        if '.xml' in link.text or '.pdf' in link.text:
            print(f'download {link.text}')  # This is a placeholder for now
        else:
            print('click')
            browser.get(browser.current_url + link.text)
            return crawler()
```

Comment: post url and desired output

Comment: The website requires a university log on. Desired output would simply be downloading all the files at the end of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.get(start_url)
def crawler():
    links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//pre/a')
    for link in links:
        if '.xml' in link.text or '.pdf' in link.text:
            print(f'download {link.text}')  # This is a placeholder for now
        else:
            print('click')
            browser.get(browser.current_url + link.text)
            crawler()
```

Per the comments, here's the code I use to wait for refresh in Selenium. Note that it is written to be part of a class so it uses self.driver, etc. BTW self.get_tags is simply a function that does a find_elements_by_tag_name for the supplied tag (using 'html' which most pages have).

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import staleness_of

    @contextmanager
    def wait_for_page_load(self, timeout=MAX_WAIT, entity='wait_for_page_load'):
        """ Wait for a new page that isn't the old page 
        """
        old_page = self.get_tags(self.driver, 'html', entity)
        yield
        webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                staleness_of(old_page[0]))
```

example call:

```
    with self.wait_for_page_load():
        logout.click()
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I already opened the browser in code above. My code currently returns a list of all the files at the first 'end node' of the file tree. I'm missing all the other 'end nodes' essentially.

Comment: OK. I see what your problem is now. The return statement was returning the first time crawler was called, terminating the 'for link in links' loop.

Comment: I would still recommend passing start_url to crawler and having crawler do the browser.get at the beginning of the function and change the recursive call to crawler to specify the child url. But it's up to you.

Comment: I end up getting a `stale element reference`, which I've gotten a couple of times. I think I need to navigate back somehow and track the links I've visited?

Comment: The reason I called `browser.get()` first is because I need to log in before crawling.

Comment: Fair enough. I hope the above solution works for you.

Comment: I'll add some code I use to wait for the page refresh. You can use a timer to wait but I've found the function more effective.

Comment: @Natasha I am expecting StaleElement exception when you run the above answer, if you see StateElement exception that's because `links` selenium references will refresh once click any link. So you have to use the index to point to the right link.